# "I had been studying", "I had been studied", "I studied"

Tags: past-tense

Are the following sentences correct? and what is the difference in meaning?

> - I had been studying for over 3 years before I reached to level B.
> - I had been studied for over 3 years before I reached to level B.
> - I studied more than 3 years before I reached to level B.

Comment: What are your own thoughts about these sentences? Sharing them would provide a good starting point for an answer.

Comment: I think it should be *for more than 3 years*

Comment: It's a bit unclear which part of the sentences you're asking about, but there is no need for the preposition "to" after "reached" in any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first sentence you use a present participle: some people also call it an active participle. You use it to talking about something that you are doing.

> I had been studying maths - *I am doing the studying*

The second sentence uses a past participle: some people call it a passive participle. You use it to talk about something that is being done to you.

> I had been studied by scientists - *the scientists are studying me*

This is probably not the meaning that you intend, so let's rule out sentence 2.

Sentence 1 is past perfect continuous: it says that you were doing something for a period of time (three years) before some event in the past (reaching level B).

Sentence 3 is past simple: you did something for an unspecified period of time, and you completed it three years before you reached level B.

Sentence 1 is closer to what you probably meant, but there is no real need to use past perfect continuous: you could just change sentence 3 from simple past to past continuous and add a **for**:

> I was studying for more than three years before I reached level B

Note that the **to** after **reached** is not required.

Answer (score 3):

> I had been studying for over 3 years before I reached to level B.

*Reach* is used transtively here, it'd be wrong if you put the preposition(to) after the verb. The use of *had been*(past perfect) is optional because "before" already marks the sequence of the events.

> I had been studied for over 3 years before I reached to level B.

Again, the preposition should be removed. "I had been studied" is a passive contruction, it would mean "you were studied by someone", which is quite nonsensical.

> I studied more than 3 years before I reached to level B.

You need to add *for* before "more than 3 years" , I'm not sure why you need to do so, maybe because *for* is usually used to indicate a period. Because it's a long period, the progressive form would fit better "I was studying. . . ", but there's no "should" here, it's still OK to use the simple form.